# EXCEL COUNT IF FUNCTION

Tags: excel

I am having trouble writing a countifs function.

I have COLUMN B with BILLING IDS and Column G with the COUNTRIES.

I want to make a countifs equation to give me the COUNT OF BILLING IDS based on COUNTRIES that are 1 (each country has a number, i just want the number 1 to come up)

So, how many times does 0075 billing id is present in the sheet with

sheet is called all ltrs

this won't work ==COUNTIFS('all ltrs'!B:B,'all ltrs'!G:G,1)

Comment: The 0075 as criteria is missing in the formula. Have a look here for the syntax and some examples: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842

Comment: Did you find it? From the function point of view, it works like this: count all the rows in the given range, where the value in the ID column is equal to 0075 and the value in the country column is equal to 1.  The formula does not work like “… count separately for each of the different ID for country 1”

Comment: Nah, I did not find it and I do not want to use a PIVOT table. -- pretend COLUMNS ABCD, Column A is BILL IDS REPEATED SEVERAL TIMES, column C is the UNIQUE FILTER so just summarizes the bill ids in column a, COLUMN B is the number each Bill ID uses, and column D should be a count of all the uses in B but adds everything up based on bill ID.

Comment: Sorry, I don’t understand your reference about pivot table. I just explained why the way you wanted use does not match with the intended use of COUNTIFS:  ```=COUNTIFS(ID_column_range,ID_of_current_row, Country_column_range, Country_of_current_row)```

Comment: If you have bill ID and country as column A and B as original list. You can use UNIQUE over both columns to create a unique list with bill ID and country, say as column E and F. Then you could use column G to count e.g. cell [G2] =COUNTIFS(A2:A100,E2,B2:B100,F2)

Comment: So, what if I have Column A as BILL ID and Column G as the Countries (in number format).

Comment: The answer is twofold:  the short answer (with high risk that the result is not what you expected): in my example above replace the B with a G (country code) and keep A (ID)

Comment: The second answer: sorry, it is better to understand how the parameters for COUNTIFS work while using it in order to avoid unintended results or mistakes. You may want to follow the link given above. It seems you still do not know what’s wrong/missing in your line and what are the references in my example line. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that I fully understand the question, however it seems that a Pivot Table and Slicer might give the desired results.

1. Country and ID are pulled into the Rows area
2. ID is also pulled into the Values area (count is default summarization since ID's are text)
3. The ID field is used in a Slicer

[image: Count instances of ID's per country]